# How to display an attachment in an email before sending but remove the file name from appearing at the bottom of the email after sending

Tags: vba, outlook

I'm trying to create a VBA code (I'm relatively new at this) that will attach a PDF to an email. I've gotten everything to work (the email is created, the file attached, and when I press 'send' the email arrives at it's destination) but when I use olByValue, 1 the file name appears as text at the end of the email after sending (in addition to the actual attachment being displayed as it should be along the top of the email).

I am trying to find a way to hide that text. I tried to use olByValue, 0 but part of our protocols at work includes manually QCing all emails before sending so that there's no possibility of accidentally sending Client A's data to Client B (the macro doesn't include the .Send command for this reason). Is there a way to be able to review the PDF while it's attached to the email before sending but not display the file name as text after sending?

I'm using Excel for 365 to create the email body and to send the data over to Outlook 365.

The line of code that pertains to the attachment is below. Thanks for any help and please let me know if I wasn't clear on something.

```
If Range("AD45") = "Update" And Range("AJ36") = "1" And Range("AJ37") = "Yes" Then
            .Attachments.Add Range("AB26").Value, olByValue, 0
            .Body = Range("Z80").Value & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & vbNewLine
    End If
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The location is determined by the message format.

The Rich Text format supports in-line attachments and thus the attachments show up in the body of the message. Plain Text and HTML formatted emails do not support this and show the attachments in a separate line under the message header but above the message body. See [Attachments show up in the message body](https://www.msoutlook.info/question/126) for more information.

For example, before attaching files to the email you need to set the `BodyFormat` property which sets an `OlBodyFormat` constant indicating the format of the body text. :

```
With objMail  
 'Set body format to HTML  
 .BodyFormat = olFormatHTML  
 .HTMLBody = "<HTML><H2>The body of this message will appear in HTML.</H2><BODY>Type the message text here. </BODY></HTML>" 

 .Display  
 End With
```

Comment: Thanks! I had to modify it a little, as the Excel range that was referenced as the email body was formatted already as we needed it, and adding the .HTMLBody messed up that formatting. But adding the .BodyFormat = olFormatHTML to the start of the code and then deleting the olByValue section from the attachment line worked for what I needed it to. I appreciate the help!